# Create new object if array has multiple ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

We have an array like

```
const arr = [{
    name: 'foo',
    age: 23,
    id: [1, 2]
}, {
    name: 'bar',
    age: 24,
    id: [3, 4]
}, {
    name: 'baz',
    age: 24,
    id: 5
}];
```

If object has array of ids then a new object should be added to the array

**expected**

```
const newArry = [{
    name: 'foo',
    age: 23,
    id: 1,
}, {
    name: 'foo',
    age: 23,
    id: 2
}, {
    name: 'bar',
    age: 24,
    id: 3
}, {
    name: 'bar',
    age: 24,
    id: 4
}, {
    name: 'baz',
    age: 24,
    id: 5
}]
```

anyone knows better way to do. Please help!!!

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of `flatMap` for this. First you will check if the id is of type array, if so then apply map on it and return the appropriate value.

```js
const arr = [{name: 'foo', age: 23, id: [1,2]}, {name: 'bar', age: 24, id: [3,4]}, {name: 'baz', age: 24, id: 5}];

const result = arr.flatMap(e=>Array.isArray(e.id) ? e.id.map(id=>({...e,id})) : e);

console.log(result);
```

However, check the browser compatibility for flatMap [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#browser_compatibility). As an alternate you can make use of reduce method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and push each id for array id and simply add object for string id.

```js
const arr = [{name: 'foo', age: 23, id: [1,2]}, {name: 'bar', age: 24, id: [3,4]}, {name: 'baz', age: 24, id: 5}],
      result = arr.reduce((r, o) => {
        if(Array.isArray(o.id)) {
          o.id.forEach(id => r.push({ ...o, id }));
        } else {
          r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
      }, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweeked array.forEach for the implementation. Hope this will be helpful.

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'foo',
    age: 23,
    id: [1, 2]
}, {
    name: 'bar',
    age: 24,
    id: [3, 4]
}, {
    name: 'baz',
    age: 24,
    id: 5
}];

const newArry = [];
arr.forEach(item => {
  if (typeof(item.id) === 'number') {
    newArry.push({
      name: item.name,
      age: item.age,
      id: item.id,
    })
  } else {
    item.id.forEach( idItem => {
      newArry.push( {
        name: item.name,
        age: item.age,
        id: idItem,
      })
    })
  }
})

console.log(newArry);
```